# How to access parent element and remove it with angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I want access to parent element from `ng-click` event's target element and remove it.

I looked some pages and angular docs and found something like below but this is not worked for me.

My Template:

```
<div class="element-which-i-want-access">
   <span>
      <button ng-click="remove(myModelObjectInCurrentScope, $event)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
   </span>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
$scope.remove = function(object, $event) {
   var el = $event.target; // this meaning as clicked <button> element 
   var myTargetElement = el.parent().parent(); // this not working
   myTargetElement.remove(); // i couldn't tried this step but i couldn't got parent element yet
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$event.target` will give the DOM element. To use `parent()` on it, it need to be wrapped as follow

```
angular.element(el).parent().parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

accepted  answer did'nt work for me. but this code did:

```
var elem= angular.element($event.currentTarget);
var parent = elem.parent().parent();
parent.remove();
```